# ubuntu 16.04 wifi keep dropping out but was working on windows 10

Tags: wireless

Qualcomm Atheros AR9227 Wireless Network Adapter

thats my card wifi keeps dropping out how do i fix it havnt used linux in a few years but after twice windows 10 deleting my files after  a update im sticking with ubuntu if the wifi problem can be fixed

Comment: some up with this and i downloaded the file

Comment: sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.157.6_all.deb
dpkg: error processing archive linux-firmware_1.157.6_all.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware_1.157.6_all.deb

Comment: when you download the file,cd to the downloads  folder for example  `cd /home/Downloads`  the run `sudo dpkg -i nic-firmware_1.157.6_all.udeb` since the filename you downloaded is not `linux-firmware_1.157.6_all.deb` but `nic-firmware_1.157.6_all.udeb`

Comment: it comes up with the same thing as before

Comment: Check `iwlist scan | egrep -i 'ssid|cipher'` if your access point shows TKIP as a cipher that is an issue.  Please edit the question to include results for `iwconfig`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the results of these terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and also: `sudo modprobe ath9k && dmesg | grep ath`. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555: up to you...  Firmware update didn't work (only Atheros problem I ever had...)

Comment: still not working keeps dropping out every few minutes